# Is EmguCV's EigenObjectRecognizer uses EigenFace?

Tags: emgucv

I want to learn that is EmguCV's EigenObjectRecognizer's has Recognize() method.But I could not found any information that is using which algorithm.I used it in my thesis and I need to know which technique is using that method.I know it uses Eigen Vector and Eigen Values but I am not sure how it uses it. Is any one know could point me ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It use a PCA-based algorithm, which is what eigenface use.